# Why does the "and" function not work in my if statement? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering why I can't use the "and" statement in my code here. I want it so that people can type either "1" or "Add" and same with multiply, but it simply doesn't work.
It's just a basic calculator.
                      I'm using the basic Python program.

```
calcUnit = input("Choose between Add(1) or Multiply(2) :")

if calcUnit == **"Add" and "1":**

  print("You choose Add!")
  num1 = input("First Number :")
  num2 = input("Second Number :")
  result = float(num1) + float(num2)
  print("Result:",result)

elif calcUnit == **"Multiply" and "2":**

  print("You choose Multiply!")
  num1 = input("First Number :")
  num2 = input("Second Number :")
  result = float(num1) * float(num2)
  print("Result:",result)

else:
  print("Welp shiii")
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you need `or`. Something can't be `"Add"` and `"1"` at the same time, can it? And by the way is written this way

```
if calcUnit == "Add" or calcUnit == "1":
```

or

```
if calcUnit in ['Add', '1']:
```